# How to write sql to show total amount as last row in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to write a SQL in postgres that list the details then the total amount as shown below?

| Item | TotalAmtSold |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 10000 |
| 1002 | 20000 |
| 1003 | 5000 |
| 1004 | 2000 |
| Total: | 30700 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROLLUP()` in your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT item, sum(totalamtsold) FROM yourtable GROUP BY ROLLUP(item)
```

Comment: If I add more columns in the select then just add those columns in the group by ROLLUP?

Comment: Yes... it depends on what you want. Give it a whirl. Best to read up on `GROUP BY` and `ROLLUP` and all the other GROUP BY options if things aren't making sense.